# Apache Commons - What is the most optimized way to compare two MultiValuedMaps?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

I'm using MultiValuedMaps from apache common i.e. org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;

I have two MultiValuedMaps as follows:

```
MultiValuedMap<String, Integer> m1 = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
m1.put("a",23);
m1.put("a",24);

MultiValuedMap<String, Integer> m2 = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
m2.put("a",24);
m2.put("a",23);
```

**What is the most efficient way to compare both the keys and values?**

I tried m1.equals(m2), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`m1.equals(m2)` should work.

Btw. you can try to use `m1.toString().equals(m2.toString())` it will convert your `MultiValuedMap` to `String` objects and make equals operation on them. But be careful with `toString()` as it will depends on map objects order.

Comment: If the value is an array, .equals will not work, which is precisely the problem I'm facing

Answer (score 0):

If the values in your map are an arrays, it will be more complicated, you should wrote your own method, which will look like this (be aware of map values sorting):

```
private static boolean areEqual(MultiValuedMap<String, String[]> first, MultiValuedMap<String, String[]> second) {
    if (first.size() != second.size() && !first.keySet().containsAll(second.keySet())) {
        return false;
    }
    List<String[]> firstValues = new ArrayList<>(first.values());
    List<String[]> secondValues = new ArrayList<>(second.values());
    if (firstValues.size() != secondValues.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < firstValues.size(); i++) {
        String[] firstArr = firstValues.get(i);
        String[] secondArr = secondValues.get(i);
        Arrays.sort(firstArr);
        Arrays.sort(secondArr);
        if (!Arrays.equals(firstArr, secondArr)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are stored as array ,then there should be indicator to compare values against keys are matching or not.

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreMultivaluedMap(MultivaluedMap<String, T> otherMap) {
    if (this == otherMap) {
        return true;
    }
    Set<String> myKeys = keySet();
    Set<String> otherKeys = otherMap.keySet();
    if (!myKeys.equals(otherKeys)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (Entry<String, List<T>> e : entrySet()) {
        List<T> myValues = e.getValue();
        List<T> otherValues = otherMap.get(e.getKey());
        if (myValues != null || otherValues != null) {
            if (myValues != null) {
                if (myValues.size() != otherValues.size()) {
                    return false;
                }
                for (T value : myValues) {
                    if (!otherValues.contains(value)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```